# What happens when an expensive operation is happening and thread freezes for longer than RxJava Interval period

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java2, intervals, rx-android

I am using RxJava Interval Like this:

```
compositeDisposable.add(
    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .flatMap(tick -> {
            return Observable.just(doWork(tick));
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::updateUI, e -> {
            disableIndicator();
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
        })
);

public Status doWork(long tick) {
    // Doing heavy task
    // Here the Status is an Enum class
    return output
}

public void updateUI(Status value) {
    // Updates UI accordingly
}
```

Everything works as expected, but I have a concern. So my `doWork()` method is doing some heavy task in bg and I am updating the UI in `updateUI()` method based on the result produced by that method.I am calling the doWork() **every second** using RxJava Interval. Usually it takes less than a second to execute the `doWork()` method. So I was just wondering what happens if I have lots of data and the `doWork()` method takes more than one seconds to execute, lets say it takes 2 seconds.But the interval will keep calling the `doWork()` method every second. Since my previous execution will take another one second to complete what will I get as return value?

Comment: They will start right after the previous work completed. You may want to use a different construct if you need time between runs: https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2017/09/fixed-rate-vs-fixed-delay-rxjava-faq.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing happens is something like this:

- Suppose the method `doWork` takes longer than a second to execute the command, the next execution gets queued BUT NOT delayed.
- Lets say in `n` th second the method does something expensive which takes 3 seconds to complete and will produce a result `A`. Since the method is being executed after 1 seconds, there will be another 3 execution which will be queued which will not take longer than a second to execute and produce and will generate result `B`,`C`,`D`.
- After `n+3` seconds you will get all four results at once. That will be `A` `B` `C` `D`

So If you are hoping to see the result `A` at `n+3` second and `B` `C` `D` after 1 seconds too (Means you don't want to get all four values at once), You need to do something like this:

```java
Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(tick -> {
        return Observable.just(doWork());
    })
    .repeat()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(value -> printUI(value), throwable -> {})
)
```